# t-SQL Preceding rows in 2 tables

Tags: t-sql, rows, partitioning

I've got t-sql problem i try to tackle for 2 days but i'm lost right now.

Let's assume we've got tables:
Fixtures:

| ID | TeamA | TeamB | GoalsA | GoalsB | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ars | Leeds | 3 | 0 | 23.03.2021 |
| 1 | Leeds | Ars | 0 | 3 | 23.03.2021 |
| 2 | Ars | WBA | 2 | 0 | 26.03.2021 |
| 2 | WBA | Ars | 0 | 2 | 26.03.2021 |
| 3 | EVE | Mcity | 1 | 0 | 23.03.2021 |
| 3 | Mcity | EVE | 0 | 1 | 23.03.2021 |
| 4 | CHE | Mcity | 2 | 2 | 26.03.2021 |
| 4 | Mcity | Che | 2 | 2 | 26.03.2021 |
| 5 | Liv | Mcity | 3 | 3 | 01.04.2021 |
| 5 | Mcity | Liv | 3 | 3 | 01.04.2021 |
| 6 | Ars | Mcity | 1 | 1 | 03.04.2021 |
| 6 | Mcity | Ars | 1 | 1 | 03.04.2021 |

Players

| PLID | PLName | Team | Rival | Date | FixID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Saka | Ars | Mcity | 03.04.2021 | 6 |

...

I want to fill in the table Players with data from 3 last events from table Fixtures. I want to sum Goals of Team and I can do that by:
joining on

```
  concat(Players.FixID,Players.Team) = concat(Fixtures.ID,Fixtures.TeamA)
```

and then querying:

```
      sum(fix.GoalsA) OVER (PARTITION BY fix.[Team] 
                      ORDER BY fix.Date
                          ROWS between 3 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING) AS 'TeamLast3G'
```

and it works perfectly. On top of that I would like to get 3 Goals conceded of the rival. Meaning if the rival is Mcity I want to look for last 3 matches and get sum of 3 last GoalsB. In the example above it would be: 3     + 2   + 1 ). I tried several different solution but feel like going in circles.
my base idea was to join on

```
 concat(Players.FixID,Players.Rival) = concat(Fixtures.ID,Fixtures.TeamA)
```

and then querying

```
  sum(fix.GoalsB) OVER (PARTITION BY fix.TeamA
                      ORDER BY fix.Date
                          ROWS between 3 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING) AS 'RivalLast3G'
```

but the response i've got just does not make any sense for me and i'm not sure what's the logic behind the result. Can you please explain me my error and correct me?

Comment: using concat in a join is a bad idea instead just join on both fields with an and -- eg `JOIN fixtures on players.fixid = fixtures.id AND players.team = fixtures.teama`

Answer (score 1):

not 100% sure what you are trying to do but if you look at this:

```
sum(fix.GoalsB) OVER (PARTITION BY fix.TeamA
                  ORDER BY fix.Date
                      ROWS between 3 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING) AS 'RivalLast3G'
```

you are summing goalsB but you are partitioning by teama -- is this what you want?

also in your first example that you says works you use a field that does not exist `fix.Team` so how could that even run?